# After updating to .net8, reference the System.Windows.Controls in the xaml editor

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3

The .NET RID changed from .NET8, so I modified the PropertyGroup in the csproj file as follows.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
  <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
  <RootNamespace>Test</RootNamespace>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
  <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
  <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
  <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I also modified the name and rid of the pubxml file.

After that, in the xaml editor, it initially normally referenced Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls  namespace, but at some point, without knowing why, the error occurred by referencing the System.Windows.Controls namespace, and auto-completion did not work.

[image]

[image]

The error is not described, but by mouse-up and looking at the type of Grid, you can see that it is "System.Windows.Controls.Grid."

When I compile it, it works normally, but it's difficult to code due to bugs in the editor.

Does anyone know why this bug is happening?

Comment: I don't have that problem with similar csproj have you updated the latest WinAPP SDK (1.4.231115000) and build tools (10.0.22621.2428)? Also can you try to close Visual Studio, delete bin & obj directories and re-open

Comment: @SimonMourier It's all the latest versions, and I've tried the methods you've suggested, but they still get bugs. I didn't get a bug at first, but it happens sometime when I code.

Answer (score 14):

**UPDATE**

The workaround `UseRidGraph` is no longer required from [WindowsAppSDKv1.4.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-144-14231219000:%7E:text=Updated%20Windows%20App%20SDK%20support%20for%20.NET%208%20RID%2Dspecific%20asset%20handling.).

---

The are the steps that works for me to upgrade from .NET 7 to .NET 8:

1. Install [.NET 8 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0).
2. Edit your *.csproj file.

   - `TargetFramework`: net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0
   - `RuntimeIdentifiers`: win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64
   - `PublishProfile`: win-$(Platform).pubxml
   - Add `UseRidGraph` and set it to `true`.

   For example:

   ```xml
   <PropertyGroup>
     <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
     <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
     <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
     <RootNamespace>WinUI3App4</RootNamespace>
     <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
     <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
     <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
     <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
     <UseRidGraph>true</UseRidGraph>
     <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
     <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
     <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

These steps might be changed in later versions of **WindowsAppSDK**. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-142-14231008000:%7E:text=There%20was%20a,x86%3C/RuntimeIdentifier%3E) from the release notes.

Comment: That's such a shame to Mictosoft that WinUI projects just cannot be even compiled "out-of-the-box" without tuning ups! That greatly shows Microsoft attitude its Desktop infrastructure!