# How can I upgrade my WinUI3 project to .NET 8.0?

Tags: .net, upgrade, winui-3, .net-8.0

I am developing a WinUI project and I noticed that .NET 8.0 was published. I really want to upgrade my project to .NET 8.0 so I read the document about [.NET upgrade assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview). I followed the steps and installed the ".NET upgrade assistant" exstension in Visual Studio. But unfortunately, the an error was thrown during the upgrade. There are two options for upgrade failure--`***.csproj`and`Finalized project dependencies`. [image: This picture is the error when I try to upgrade a test project to .NET 7.0,but the error which has been thrown was the same]

I don't know how to solve this question because the upgeade assistant seems like a preview so there aren't many documents about it. So I hope someone could help me with this problem.

My native language is not English, so there may be some grammatical errors in this question, please point them out if they affect your reading. Thank you very much!

Comment: Test.csproj throw the error:" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' >= '8.0'" compares the value of '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' that evaluates to '' instead of a number."(this sentence was translated by translator so it may not be very exact). And I noticed that the items that throw warnings mentioned that WindowsAppSDK don't support .NET 7.0 or .NET 8.0, but I think it should support because I have found a WinUI3 project based on .NET 8.

Comment: What is the error message for those issues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77507023/2411960

Comment: Thank you very much. According to your answer to that question, I upgrade my project to .NET 8.0 successfully. I only thought of upgrade assistant before, and forgot I can upgrade my project by modify the csproj file. I'm very sorry to trouble you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77507023/2411960)

, the problem has been solved. Thanks for Andrew KeepCoding's answer to that question.