Throw exception when change project to .NET 8
I have project in C# on .NET 7 and with WinUI 3, and I try change to .NET 8 because my project use in KlearTouch.MediaPlayer.WinUI for display media and now I want change to use in MediaPlayerElement of WinUI 3 that supported it.
For this I need change to .NET 8 and I update:

Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK from 1.1.1 version to 1.6.241114003 version.
Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools from 10.0.22621.1 to 10.0.22621.756

I update this because MediaPlayerElement of WinUI 3 required this versions.
And since I change the versions of the two packages, my project crash.
In output window in visual studio I get this:

The program has exited with code 3221226356 (0xc0000374).

What can I do? How to fix it?

The exit code 0xC0000374 is the value returned when heap corruption is detected: - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/troubleshoot-application-service-crashing-behavior for how to get data

You might want to make the updates step by step and not all at once.

About upgrade from .NET 7 to .NET 8, you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77507023

Now my project is run! I instaled winsdksetup and its fixed. but I have another problem : my project run only in my computer, when I do Publish single file and self-contained and I try to open in another computer its not work - my app not run. my changes its: I move to NET 8 and I update Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK to Version=1.6.240923002 and Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools to 10.0.22621.756.
In my computer my project run also with Publish and from visual studio.
What can be problem that publish not work?
